# When I record my screen using quicktime, it looks like this:

Tags: mac, audio, catalina, screen-capture, quicktime

Using most recent Mac and Quicktime software.

When I record my screen using QuickTime, and choose to record a selected portion, the resulting recording looks like this:

[image: strange pixelation error]

What is supposed to be a black and white video shows these strange diagonal pixelated patterns, and then some random green pixels in the same pattern. You can still see the video playing underneath, but its totally obscured, like its a puzzle that's been rearranged if that makes sense.

Anyway, what's happening? This doesn't happen if I record my whole screen. As far as I can tell it only happens when I choose a window to record in.

Not sure if this is relevant, but I'm using a plugin called Soundflower to record my computer's internal audio along with the QuickTime screen recording of the video.

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like some sort of copy protection. What exactly are you trying to record?

Comment: it's my own content, to share with clients. I'm a filmmaker. It's easier than exporting, which can be very time-consuming. So no copy protection.

Comment: Can you give some technical details? - I.e. stuff like: which program displays the video, which format is it in, are you capturing a full screen with "ornaments", or just the video?

Comment: the video is screen recorded and played back using QuickTime, its a .mov file automatically, and I'm not sure about the ornaments, but I think it is just video and internal computer audio.

Comment: You're using QuickTime to record the screen - right? - So what's playing on the screen? This is the question I'm asking. I.e. What are you trying to record? This is the third time I ask, I can't give any more advice in this thread before that is answered.

Comment: So I'll try to clarify. In the case of the screenshot I took that I posted above, what was originally playing on my screen was a black and white film that I made, which you can't see any of the details of because of this weird pixelation that is happening. Its playing in an open window of Adobe Premiere Pro, which is the ending software I use.

But basically, whats on the screen is irrelevant to why this is happening. I tested it by just recording my desktop and it did the same thing. So I could be recording this webpage and it would turn out looking similar to the picture above.